# How to print Unicode "u033F" multiple times continuously in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In My Code, QLabel_2  contains  Unicode for Double overline (u"\u033F")  and QLabel_3 contains Unicode for Draw Box(u"\2550").
**Problem:** Unicode for double overline is not printing continuously in QLabel, whereas, we use this Unicode in the normal print statement, it's print continuously (Line No 11) and at the same time Unicode for draw box(In QLabel_3), it's work fine. How to resolve it (Continuously print double overline)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets

class Layout_sample(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(). __init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Layout Sample")
        print((u"\u033f"+u"\u033f"+u"\u033f"+u"\u033f"+u"\u033f"+u"\u033f")      ##its work  file
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.hbox1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("F3F3F3F3F3")
        self.lbl2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(u"\u033f"+u"\u033f"+u"\u033f"+u"\u033f"+u"\u033f"+u"\u033f")     
        self.lbl3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(u"\u2550"+u"\u2550"+u"\u2550"+u"\u2550")


        self.hbox1.addWidget(self.lbl1)
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.lbl2)
        self.hbox3.addWidget(self.lbl3)

        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox1)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox2)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox3)
        self.vbox.addStretch()
        self.vbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = Layout_sample()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `033f` code is a [*combining character*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). This means that it **requires** another character paired to it in order to be *correctly* displayed. This is similar to other more standard combining characters, like the "umlaut" (diaeresis), which is normally paired with a compatible letter and almost never shown alone.

Now, the "problem" is that Qt uses single character combinations (including combining characters) to evaluate actual size and drawing based on font features, which mostly refers to kerning/advance (and this is probably the source of your issue): the double overlines alone are not combined to anything (if not themselves), so it defaults to a "sum" of a combining character to "no character" (which defaults to "one character").

A possible workaround would be to pair each double line character with a space:

```
self.lbl2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(u'\u033f ' * 6)
```

But that won't work very well, for two reasons:

- the width of an "empty" combining character is not always known and transparent;
- if the font doesn't properly support combining character spacings, you'll end up with something like `=   =   =   =` (or not *completely black* lines);

So, I doubt there's an actual and proper solution for what you're trying to achieve (besides using the `u2550` character), but if your purpose is to *draw* a double overline over a specified amount of blank spaces, you might prefer a simpler option: use QPainter and draw lines based on the current font metrics.